# WinDbg script not working

Tags: windbg

I often need to type in a bunch of `.srcpath+`, `.sympath+`, and `.exepath+` to load paths in order to debug a crash dump. I like to put these settings into a script file so to make my life easier. From the command I tried:

```
$$>< E:\Supports\envs.wdb
```

I got errors:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

for each line I added in the script. But If entered the lines manually, everything was fine.

I also tried to run `windbg.exe -c "$$>< E:\Supports\envs.wdb"`, and I got the same errors.

Any helps would be greatly appreciated.

Btw, I like to put each path in a separate line so I can quickly edit paths in the script using block mode. With mainactual's help, debugging a crash dump becomes very quick for me. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Path commands are bit tricky since the syntax is

```
.srcpath[+] [directory [; ...]]
```

which makes command

```
.srcpath C:\Foo
.srcpath+ C:\Bar
```

to be interpreted as a single line command

```
.srcpath C:\Foo;.srcpath+ C:\Bar
```

To work around this, use "-marks

```
.srcpath "C:\Foo"
.srcpath+ "C:\Bar"
```

or

```
.srcpath "C:\Foo;C:\Bar"
```

And notice also that you don't need "-marks for white space:

```
.srcpath "C:\Foo Bar;C:\Bar"
```